# US patent appl. # us20140027014 is in violation of Laminar Technologies patent # 5842617

Tags: patent-infringement, us20140027014, us5842617

An ex-employee has taken confidential drawings and designs and applied for a patent that infringes on our companies prior patents. What do I do to stop this?

Comment: I have no idea, but patents do not infringe other patents. Making, selling, importing and using a product are things that can infringe.

Answer (score 1):

In google patents US5842617 for it says

```
Date    Code    Event   Description
Jan 18, 2011    FP  Expired due to failure to pay maintenance fee
```

So the patent expired three years ago. They appear to be trying to solve related problems.